# Read Arguments From CMD and Concatenate Strings in Bat File

Tags: matlab, batch-file

I have the following code in my bat file which saved as MyLM.bat:

```
@echo off
matlab -automation -r "addpath('C:\Users\mojtaba\BrainModel');AddPathes;MyLM('MT5Test_LM')" > matlab_output.log
exit
```

In which i simply add the main path and then necessary paths and then i run my function (Which is MyLM). I am running the following code from my matlab command prompt :

```
!start "MATLAB test" /Min /B MyLM.bat
```

and it works fine and i am happy! So i can run different instances of matlab separately using different bat files. What will makes me happier is that i can pass my argument (which is 'MT5Test_LM') from matlab command prompt. So i dont need to save different bat files. What i actually need is to have some code like this :

```
!start "MATLAB test" /Min /B MyLM.bat 'MT5Test_LM'
```

then i need some piece of codes in my bat file to read this argument and concatenate some strings.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: What strings do you need to concatenate? It looks to me like all you need to do is replace 'MT5Test_LM' with %1 in the batch file.

Comment: I wanted to concatenate the string i read from bat file with may basic codes "addpath('C:\Users\mojtaba\BrainModel');AddPathes;...." to make the proper command. It is solved btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the input argument of the batch file (`%1`)?
See, e.g., [this manual](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true) on batch file input argument.

You might want your bathc file to look like

```
matlab -r "myLM( %1 )"
```